# devexpress при переключении вкладок сбрасывается ширина колонок в таблице

Tags: c#, devexpress

Не могу найти решение следующей **проблемы**:
Есть две вкладки с таблицами. Как сделать так, чтобы выбранная ширина колонок таблицы не изменялась в дефолтное значение после переключения вкладок, а оставалась такой, как её настроил пользователь? Devexpress всегда все сбрасывает в начальное состояние после переключения между вкладками.

Comment: а что если установить ширину колонок таблицы ручками, и Вы бы уточнили что у вас [tag:asp.net]/[tag:asp.net-mvc]/[tag:winforms]/[tag:wpf]

Comment: так в том то и дело, что пользователь хочет настроить под себя колонки и чтобы в течении работы они не изменялись. Если я настрою руками, они будут или фиксированные, или каждый раз сбрасываться в некое начальное состояние. wpf я так понимаю.

Comment: ну так тогда Вы где то должны сохранять измененные пользователем значения, и их использовать для установки ширины колонок

Answer (score 2):

Смог решить проблему. На всех GridControl были события Loaded, в которых каждый раз устанавливалась отпимальная ширина столбцов BestFitColumns(). Заменил на событие Initialized.

Answer (score 0):

для сохранения/восстановления пользовательских настроек,
когда это необходимо я использую сериализацию
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Уточните что за используете.
Для Data Grid примеры:
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument772
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6796